# Twitter bootstrap highlight any word

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Boostrap TypeAhead along with MVC4 - is there any way I can change the javascript for typeahead, to highlight ANY word in the search box, as opposed to exactly what is in the search box eg. if I type Outlook, it highlights Outlook in the 4 items in the drop down:

[image: Typeahead ss1]

However, if I type "outlook access" (which appears in the 4th item above) - it IS returned in the JSON from my controller, however, TypeAhead does not display it as "Outlook access" does not appear as one string in the entries:

[image: Typeahead ss2]

I suspect the answer is here (typeahead JS) but not certain:

```
, highlighter: function (item) {
  var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
  return item.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
    return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
  })
}

, render: function (items) {
  var that = this

  items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
    i = $(that.options.item).attr('data-value', item)
    i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item))
    return i[0]
  })

  items.first().addClass('active')
  this.$menu.html(items)
  return this
}
```

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to override `matcher` to return all the results, by adding this to your typeahead options:

```
matcher: function(item) { return true; }
```

By default it does a basic string match to filter them down, but as your controller is already returning the items you want it's okay to show them all.

This will get the items displaying though the highlighter won't highlight anything since "outlook access" isn't found. You can override the `highlighter` method via the options in a similar way. If the controller is returning results in a specific order, you may also want to override the `sorter` method to return the items as-is.